# How do I determine how many elements in a vector contain a pattern from a second vector?

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I am trying to determine whether a vector contains multiple patterns. I have vectors `names` and `patterns`.

For a simple example I have:

```
names <- c("john_burgess", "pablo_gorges", "pear_trapper", "john_vaccant")
```

I would like to know which of the elements in `names` contains one of the following patterns:

```
patterns<- c("john", "gorge")
```

My actual data comprises a `names` vector of [1:1126] and a `patterns` vector of [1:1163]. I have been able to work with only one pattern at a time, e.g. "john", but I would like to use all the patterns at once. My desired output would look something like this (so that I could then move on and do further analyses):

```
names         patterns
john_burgess  john
john_vaccant  john
pablo_gorges  gorge
```

I have gotten so lost looking through `grep`, `stringr::str_extract`, and `dplyr::filter` help files and only get errors as soon as I try use more than one pattern. I have removed _ in `names` and it made no difference. I know this must be possible and that it's probably a simple bit of coding but I just can't get it to work. Sorry if this question has already been asked and answered (if so, please point me to it)! I would just really appreciate a nudge in the right direction.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try with`grep(paste(patterns,collapse="|"),  names, value = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
library(stringr)
map(set_names(patterns, patterns), ~ 
      names[str_detect(names, .x)], .id = 'patterns') %>%
   enframe(name = "patterns", value = "names") %>% 
   unnest(c(names))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  patterns names       
#  <chr>    <chr>       
#1 john     john_burgess
#2 john     john_vaccant
#3 gorge    pablo_gorges
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
stack(lapply(setNames(patterns, patterns), grep, x = names, value = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks so much akrun! That's just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution using `regmatches`

```
df <- data.frame(cbind(names,
                 patterns = regmatches(names,gregexpr(paste0(patterns,collapse = "|"),names))))
```

such that

```
> df
         names patterns
1 john_burgess     john
2 pablo_gorges    gorge
3 pear_trapper         
4 john_vaccant     john
```

**DATA**

```
names <- c("john_burgess", "pablo_gorges", "pear_trapper", "john_vaccant")
patterns<- c("john", "gorge")
```

Comment: I like this solution too. Didn't know I wanted to keep the blanks in the patterns column until I saw this. Very useful! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way with `stringr` could be to paste the `patterns` and extract them using `str_extract`.

```
library(stringr)

data.frame(names, patterns = str_extract(names, str_c(patterns, collapse = "|")))

#         names patterns
#1 john_burgess     john
#2 pablo_gorges    gorge
#3 pear_trapper     <NA>
#4 john_vaccant     john
```